# Passing async function as argument

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, grequests

I am trying to use use grequests to make a single HTTP call asynchronously.
All goes find until I try to call a function (`handle_cars`) to handle the response.
The problem is that the function is an async function and it I don't know how to await it while passing.

Is this even possible?

I need the function to be async because there is another async function I need to call from it. Another solution would be to be able to call and await the other async function (`send_cars`) from inside the sync function.

```py
async def handle_cars(res):
    print("GOT IT")
    await send_cars()
```

```py
async def get_cars():
    req = grequests.get(URL, hooks=dict(response=handle_cars))
    job = grequests.send(req, grequests.Pool(1))
```

How do I set the response argument to await the function? Or how do I await `send_cars` if I make `handle_cars` synchronous?

Thanks

Comment: asyncio and g-event are 2 different asynchronous frameworks. Why don't you use something like aiohttp? I'm not sure if the hooks are called from a different greenlet, and if so, I'm not sure how asyncio will handle it without using threadsafe functions.

Comment: @Bharel well I tried using aiohttp but just like almost every other alternative everyone, including the documentation seems to only care about sending multiple requests asynchronously. That's not my case. I want to send a single request but keep doing things while i'ts completed (imagine a loop after the request in  `get_cars`). When It is completed I want it to do something with the result (like running `handle_cars`). I could not find a way to do that with aiohttp

Comment: The way to do that using the asyncio framework is to create a task, (`asyncio.create_task()`) and add a callback for completion using `task.add_done_callback()`.

Lemme write the complete answer below

Answer (score 1):

According to the OP's comments, he wishes to create a request in the background, and call a callback when it finishes.

The way to do so can be implemented using `asyncio.create_task()` and using `task.add_done_callback()`.

A simpler way however, will work by creating a new coroutine and running it in the background.

Demonstrated using `aiohttp`, it will work in the following way:

```
async def main_loop():
    task = asyncio.create_task(handle_cars(URL))
    while True:
        ...

async def handle_cars(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            await send_cars()
```

Comment: this does not work. I have tried it and If I have other functions running it will still wait for the request to complete to resume them. I think I will have to go with threads, the only missing part seems to be calling the async function and awaiting it as callback.

Comment: @Tiago doesn't make sense. What are your other functions? Are they not async?